# Change Login name (Windows user) for an existing SQL user on the Database server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a SQL 2012 database and our users are set up via Windows Authentication to connect to a specific database -  say DatabaseA.

It looks like this: **Windows user** "*DomainA/abcd*", is mapped to a **user** "*abcd*" in DatabaseA, which has a default **schema**  "*abcd*" which in turn owns a bunch of tables. Remote users log into their laptops (as DomainA/abcd), connect via VPN and are able to query data from the SQL server (they pull data from their default schema, based on their Windows login).

It all works fine, however, now we are moving to a new domain.

Our users will be logging in as "DomainB/abcd" and when they try to connect to *their* tables on the server, no data is being returned since "DomainA/abcd" and "DomainB/abcd" are different users.

**What am I trying to achieve:** Can I get the DB user "abcd" which is currently mapped to Windows login "DomainA/abcd", to point to Windows login "DomainB/abcd". Is that even possible?

If not, what are the alternatives. We want to avoid dropping the schema/tables and the user and then recreate everything again.

**What have I tried:** I tried `ALTER USER` and `sp_change_users_login` to no avail.

`ALTER USER [DomainB\abcd] WITH LOGIN = [abcd]` returns `Cannot remap user to login 'abcd', because the login is already mapped to a user in the database.` - Makes perfect sense.

`EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'abcd', 'DomainB\abcd'; GO` returns `Terminating this procedure. The User name 'abcd' is absent or invalid.` - [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says this could be used to map a db user to a new SQL login, no mention of a Windows login.

I'm a member of the sysadmin role on the DB server, so I don't think that it is a permission issue.

Comment: You'll have to drop the `USER` `[DomainA\abcd]` first, before you can `CREATE` the `USER` `[DomainB\abcd]` for the `LOGIN` `abcd`.

Comment: @Lamu - After I DROP `USER[DomainA\abcd] `, CREATE `USER [DomainB\abcd]`, it still does not let me associate `abcd` with `[DomainB\abcd]`, keeps telling me that `abcd` is mapped to a different user.

Comment: Then `USER[DomainA\abcd]` wasn't mapped to `abcd` like your question states. Therefore what user *is* it mapped to? What does `SELECT dp.[name]
FROM sys.syslogins l
     JOIN sys.database_principals dp on l.sid = dp.sid
WHERE l.[name] = N'abcd';` return?

Comment: @Lamu - Your query with `...WHERE l.[name] = N'abcd'` returns nothing, but with `...WHERE l.[name] = N'DOMAINA\abcd'` returns `abcd`

Comment: IN essence, the login is `DomainA\abcd` and the principal is `abcd`

Comment: What we do domain transfer last week, we create domainB\abcd window user first. After that, run script ALTER USER [domainA\abcd] WITH LOGIN=[DomainB\abcd] and NAME=[domainB\abcd], and it is works for us keep all the permission

Comment: @TonyDong - But we want to keep the user `abcd` and the schema `abcd` intact, just change the login for user `abcd` to `DomainB\abcd`.

Comment: ALTER USER [domainA\abcd] WITH LOGIN=[DomainB\abcd] and NAME=[abcd], does this works for you? Do you know that you can rename it in SSMS?

Comment: @TonyDong - I think it needs to be `ALTER USER [abcd] WITH LOGIN=[DomainB\abcd] , NAME=[abcd]`, it seems to be updating the properties for the `abcd` user, but I'll need to do some more testing tomorrow. I'll report what I find - thank you!

Comment: @TonyDong - `ALTER USER [abcd] WITH LOGIN=[DomainB\abcd] , NAME=[abcd]` works for what I need, please put it in an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Fun fact - I had tried this command as well, but had omitted the `.. NAME = [abcd]` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When SQL Server user domain name changes, at this time, we still want to keep the current database user setting and don't want to recreate those users, we can use SQL script to update the user domain as follow:

```
ALTER USER [abcd] WITH LOGIN = [DomainB\abcd], NAME = [abcd]
```

I am glad that works for you.